# How to add a coupon feature into my code in java

Tags: java, methods

I am learning java, and in my code, I wanted to add a coupon feature making my items cheaper. Here is my code:

```
// instance fields
String productType;
double price;


// constructor method
public Store(String product, double initialPrice) {
  productType = product;
  price = initialPrice;
}



// increase price method
public void modifyPrice(double priceInputed){
  double newPrice = price + priceInputed;
  price = newPrice;
  
}

// main method
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Store lemonade = new Store("Lemonade", .75);    
  Store cookie = new Store("Cookie", 1.00);
  lemonade.modifyPrice(6.5);
  cookie.modifyPrice(1);

  System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", cookie.price) + "$" + " For a cookie");
  
  System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", lemonade.price) + "$" + " For a lemonade"); 
  
}
}
```

What I mean by coupon is something like this:

```
public void coupon(String codeEntered){
    String code = "freecookies";

    if (codeEntered.equals(code)) {

cookie.modifyPrice(-1);

}else{

       System.out.println("Invalid Coupon!")

}

     
  }
```

So when the main method has something like `Store coupon = new coupon("freecookies");`

The cookies are cheaper!
Thanks for any help!

Comment: What have you tried? From a real-world perspective, coupons are typically applied at checkout on a cart of items and not necessarily to an item itself. The register/clerk knows which item(s) the coupon applies to and can tell you the modified price.

Comment: I have tried the example I provided which is the coupon method, and I have also tried more than I could not remember. This addition is a small test, not exactly a real-world example. I just want to see if inputting a coupon code can make a method make the cookie object cheaper?

Comment: Assuming you're not willing to change the design - your `coupon` method has no reference to the `Store cookie` variable. Try passing it in or having it in context of that method (for instance, a class variable), or if `coupon` is a method of `Store` instances, use `this` instead of `cookie`.

Comment: You should probably have a `class Coupon` with a `String code` property. If coupons are always a percentage (or fixed amount) off, then you might have a numeric property for that; otherwise, you may want the Strategy design pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to note is that `new` is reserved for constructors, so it can not be any method you'd like. Instead, you'd have to call the method on `cookie` and do a little change by removing the reference to cookie inside the method.

```
public void coupon(String codeEntered){
    
    String code = "freecookies";

    if (codeEntered.equals(code)) {
      modifyPrice(-1); // equivalent to this.modifyPrice(-1);
    }else{
       System.out.println("Invalid Coupon!")
    }
}
```

but then it will reduce the price of non-cookies as well if you use

```
lemonade.coupon("freecookies");
```

To solve this, you might want to add a map of applicable coupon codes and the discount values to your Store. so something like

```
Map<String, Double> discounts = new HashMap<>();
discounts.put("freecookies", -1.00);
Store cookie = new Store("Cookie", 1.00, discounts);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Could you point me to a guide about how to insert that HashMap?

Comment: sure. you'd need to add it to what is labeled as "instance fields". 

to set the map up in the main method, you can use the constructor method (as I did) or add a setter (like `modifyPrice`) which will take the Map as an argument.

also note that multiple constructors are fine, so you can have two arguments or three arguments

Comment: When I copy and paste 

"Map<String, Double> discounts = new HashMap<>();
discounts.add("freecookies", -1.00);
Store cookie = new Store("Cookie", 1.00, discounts);" 

I get: 



"Store.java:6: error: <identifier> expected
 discounts.add("freecookies", -1.00);
              ^
Store.java:6: error: illegal start of type
 discounts.add("freecookies", -1.00);
               ^
2 errors"

Comment: ah sorry, it should be `put` - i had a different approach before where you just store applicable codes.

Comment: Where did you mean to write put

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233252/discussion-between-thinkgruen-and-yaroslav-o).